# How to search for exact values in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a search function. However, it searches for all elements that contain the entered value. For example, there are the following elements: 44564, 76436, 445. When I enter "445", it shows "44564" and "445", but I need only 445. Or if I enter "64", then nothing should be shown, but "44564" and "76436" are shown. How to fix it?

case_list.html

```
<div>
    <h3>Search</h3>
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'case_search' %}">
        <input type="search" type="text" name="q" prequired placeholder="Put value">
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
  {% for case in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>{{ case.name }}</p>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Views.py

```
class CaseView(ListView):
    model = Case
    template_name = 'case_list.html'

class CaseSearch(ListView):
    template_name = 'case_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Case.objects.filter(name__icontains=self.request.GET.get("q"))
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["q"] = self.request.GET.get("q")
        return context
```

Urls.py

```
    path('case_list/', CaseView.as_view(), name='case_list'),
    path('case_list/search/', CaseSearch.as_view(), name="case_search"),
```

Answer (score 5):

Use iexact for exact matches. Check out the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#iexact

```
Case.objects.filter(name__iexact=self.request.GET.get("q"))
```